# Is it safe to use createHTMLDocument to sanitize HTML?

Tags: javascript, xss, client-side

i'm wondering how safe it is to use `createHTMLDocument` to do HTML sanitization. I've tried to implement it like this:

```
function sanitize(string) {
  var elm = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().body;
  elm.innerHTML = string;
  // traverse and filter elm to only allow whitelisted elements and attributes
  // e.g. use https://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js
  var cleaned_fragment = whitelist_filter(elm);
  elm = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().body;
  elm.appendChild(cleaned_fragment);

  return elm.innerHTML;
}
```

It seems to work fine with all XSS attacks i've throw at it (no script evaluation or requests triggered). But I got a feeling it might be a bad idea, im I missing something?

I've created a [jsfiddle if someone wants to experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/sYdJy/).

Comment: Are you trusting a client side javascript to sanitize the HTML?  If I were an attacker, I'd simply bypass the sanitization completely by not calling your function.  Sanitization has to be done server-side.

Comment: How would you bypass it? lets say this is a case where some client side javascript fetches from a server API that returns unsafe html that you would like to sanitize and insert into the page

Comment: @JohnDeters That depends very much on the context. Html encoding can happen on the client a web application where javascript weaves the data into the html for displaying on the same machine. You could bypass it, but that'd be like a script kiddy who proudly hacks 127.0.0.1.

Comment: In the case I mention wouldn't a bug in a sanitized be equally bad either if it's done server or client side?

Comment: Some libraries are made for that task, like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify). It use `DOMParser`, `createHTMLDocument` or `toStaticHTML`

Answer (score 8):

You should use the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse HTML when available, and only fall back to `DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument` if the former is unavailable.

In Opera Presto, I observed network activity when I passed `<img src=...>` (but not `<video>`).
Internet Explorer 9- is worse: media, styles and event listeners will be activated with this method. IE10+ supports DOMParser, so if your audience uses IE10+, then you're safe.

Comment: Thanks, did know about `DOMParser`. Ok good to know, i noticed that Chrome tries to fetch img tags even when in a detached dom tree but does not if in a new document.

Comment: Did NOT know about* :)

Comment: @MattiasWadman If you don't mind loosing lots of potentially dangerous tags and attributes, you could also try the global [`toStaticHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method in IE 8 + 9.

Answer (score 2):

Refering innerHTML of generated HTMLElement causes mXSS - a kind of DOM based XSS.

e.g, the code following causes mXSS at IE.

```
var s = "<listing>&lt;img src=1 onerror=alert(1)&gt;</listing>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString( s, "text/html" );
div.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
```

therefore, you have to manipulate as HTMLElement, don't refer innerHTML.

```
div.appendChild( doc.body.childNodes[ 0 ] );
```

see http://utf-8.jp/public/20140807/shibuyaxss.pdf and http://utf-8.jp/public/rickdom/

Comment: mXSS is really interesting and make you feel that html sanitize is a sad mess to deal with :) I guess server side sanitize is the only "sane" way but still really really hard and a never ending battle.